# Spring MVC Controllers Unit Test not calling @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit

I have a set of Controllers in the application and a class annotated as `@ControllerAdvice` which sets up certain data elements that are used in each of these controllers. I'm using `Spring MVC 3.2` and have Junits for these controllers. When I run the Junit the control is not going to the `ControllerAdvice` class wheres it works fine if I deploy the app in `Tomcat` and submit a request through browser.

Any thoughts please?.

Comment: Appreciate an update on this. I am facing similar issue where @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) annotated method in a @ControllerAdvice class is not called via unit test - webAppContextSetup(wac).build(). ExceptionHandler annotated method is called when deployed as webapp.

Comment: The correct response to this problem has changed over time. See @Matt Byrne's answer towards the end: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28727831/2288986

Comment: The same issue is happening for WebTestClient call. Any solution?

Comment: Make sure the exception is not thrown in the filter chain.

Answer (score 146):

After using the answer from @eugene-to and another similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24765219/945789) I found limitations and raised an issue on Spring: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12751

As a result, Spring test introduced the ability to register `@ControllerAdvice` classes in the builder in 4.2. If you are using *Spring Boot* then you will need 1.3.0 or later.

With this improvement, if you are using standalone setup then you can set one or more `ControllerAdvice` instances like so:

```
mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new YourControllerAdvice())
            .build();
```

**Note:** the name `setControllerAdvice()` may not make it immediately obvious but you can pass many instances to it, since it has a var-args signature.

Comment: I Add something for thoses, Like me, who are annoyed by the spring validator with the trick above : 


this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourController)

                .setValidator(mock(Validator.class))
                .setControllerAdvice(new CaissierExceptionHandler())
                .build();

Comment: If you're using webAppContextSetup instead of standaloneSetup, you may have forgotten @EnableWebMvc annotation.  See answer below by tunguski https://stackoverflow.com/a/18911362/5570214.

Comment: setContollerAdvice is not working when i was using standaloneSetup in Spring 4.2.X version.

Comment: What if the advice applies for all controllers ? Do i have to register them manually one by one ?

Comment: The same issue is happening for WebTestClient call. Any solution?

Answer (score 42):

Suppose you have class MyControllerAdvice  annotated with @ControllerAdvice that has methods annotated with @ExceptionHandler. For MockMvc you can easily add this class as exception resolver.

```
@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(myControllers)
        .setHandlerExceptionResolvers(createExceptionResolver())
        .build();
}

private ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver createExceptionResolver() {
    ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver exceptionResolver = new ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver() {
        protected ServletInvocableHandlerMethod getExceptionHandlerMethod(HandlerMethod handlerMethod, Exception exception) {
            Method method = new ExceptionHandlerMethodResolver(MyControllerAdvice.class).resolveMethod(exception);
            return new ServletInvocableHandlerMethod(new MyControllerAdvice(), method);
        }
    };
    exceptionResolver.afterPropertiesSet();
    return exceptionResolver;
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me using async request handling

Comment: Great answer, but you will also need to set the `MessageConverter`s for your `exceptionResolver` if your resolver returns any kind of object. See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25881974/945789

Answer (score 27):

I had similar problem when trying to test `ExceptionHandler` annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. In my case I had to add `@Configuration` file with `@EnableWebMvc` annotation to `@ContextConfiguration` on test class.

So my test looked like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
  RestProcessingExceptionHandler.class,
  TestConfiguration.class,
  RestProcessingExceptionThrowingController.class })
public class TestRestProcessingExceptionHandler {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @Autowired
  WebApplicationContext wac;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
  }

  @Configuration
  // !!! this is very important - conf with this annotation 
  //     must be included in @ContextConfiguration
  @EnableWebMvc
  public static class TestConfiguration { }

  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/tests")
  public static class RestProcessingExceptionThrowingController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/exception", method = GET)
    public @ResponseBody String find() {
      throw new RestProcessingException("global_error_test");
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testHandleException() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/tests/exception"))
      .andExpect(new ResultMatcher() {
        @Override
        public void match(MvcResult result) throws Exception {
          result.getResponse().getContentAsString().contains("global_error_test");
        }
      })
      .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }
}
```

With `@EnableWebMvc` configuration my test passed.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext :(

Comment: This worked for me, but I was able to just add @EnableWebMvc to the test class itself rather than including the TestConfiguration class, i.e.:
`@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
...
@EnableWebMvc
public class TestRestProcessingExceptionHandler {`

Answer (score 21):

This code is working for me:

```
public class MyGlobalExceptionHandlerTest {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    HealthController healthController;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(healthController)
            .setControllerAdvice(new GlobalExceptionHandler())
            .build();
    }

    @Test(groups = { "services" })
    public void testGlobalExceptionHandlerError() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(healthController.health())]
               .thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Unexpected Exception"));
        mockMvc.perform(get("/health")).andExpect(status().is(500));
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of spring boot did that work with? with 1.5.6 this code never calls my controlleradvice

Comment: @Bikesh , it worked for me , thanks a lot , you saved my time .

Answer (score 7):

I've been struggling with the same thing for quite some time.  After much digging, the best reference was the Spring documentation:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework

In short, if you are simply testing a controller and its methods then you can use the *'standaloneSetup'* method which creates a simple Spring MVC configuration.  This will **not** include your error handler that you annotate with @ControllerAdvice.

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new AccountController()).build();
}

// ...
```

To create a more complete Spring MVC configuration that **does** contain your error handler you should use the following setup:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("test-servlet-context.xml")
public class AccountTests {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: You still need to initialise the mockMvc, which is not shown in the above example: 
  @Before
  public void setUp()  {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

Comment: You can use .setControllerAdvice(xxx) with the StandaloneMockMvcBuilder to inject your ControllerAdvice bean

Comment: @frno saved my life. This is the simplest solution. `mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setControllerAdvice(new MyAppExceptionHandler()).build();`

Answer (score 4):

The `ControllerAdvice` should be picked up by `@WebMvcTest`, see also [Spring-Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests) Works so far for me.

Example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(ProductViewController.class)
```

Comment: This works for me with spring-boot 2.3 and Junit 5. Even `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` is not needed,

Comment: It does work with JUnit-5, but in my case not inside the parameterized tests...cant figure out why... @smile any ideas why? have you tried that?

Comment: @my- would need to look at code. May be you can ask a new question with code and complete details?

Answer (score 2):

When using @WebMvcTest with specific controllers, controller advice will not be used by the spring configuration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12979.

You can explicitly tell the spring, via the @Import annotation, to use the controller advice:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AppController.class)
@Import(AppControllerAdvice.class)
class AppControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
}
```

Comment: Instead of the most voted solution (Setting up the `MockMvc` using the builder) this `@Import` was the solution for me. When i was using the `MockMvcBuilders` my custom `WebMvcConfigurer` implementation was not picked up.

Answer (score 1):

@tunguski sample code works but it pays to understand how things work. This is just one way to set things up.

`@EnableWebMvc` is equivalent to following in a spring configuration file

`<mvc:annotation-driven />`

Essentially for things to work you need to initialize Spring Mvc and load all your controllers and bean references. So following could be a valid setup as well as an alternate

Following is how you would setup the test class

```java
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath: "classpath:test-context.xml" })
    @WebAppConfiguration    
    public class BaseTest {

        @Autowired
        WebApplicationContext wac;

        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void setUp()  {
            mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
        }
    }
```

And following could be the spring configuration for the test

```xml
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.base.package.controllers" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue while writing controller tests with [spock](http://spockframework.org/) (groovy). My test class was originally written like:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@SpringBootTest
@Category(RestTest)
class FooControllerTest extends Specification {
  def fooService = Mock(FooService)
  def underTest = new FooController(FooService)
  def mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(underTest).build()
....
}
```

This caused ControllerAdvice to be ignored. Changing the code to to Autowire the mocks  fixed the problem.

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@SpringBootTest
@Category(RestTest)
class FooControllerTest extends Specification {

  @AutowiredMock
  FooService FooService

  @Autowired
  MockMvc mockMvc
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide more info, and maybe some actual code and/or config files, before you can expect specific answers. That said, based on the little you have provided, it sounds like the annotated bean is not being loaded.

Try adding the following to your test applicationContext.xml (or equivalent spring config file, if you are using one).

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.path.to.package" />
```

Alternatively, you may need to 'manually' load the contexts within the tests by including the following annotations before your test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to use asyncDispatch in your test; the regular testing framework is broken with asynchronous controllers.

Try the approach in: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/AsyncTests.java

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way it's to add Your @ControllerAdvice annotated class to @ContextConfiguration.

I had to change from this

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = OrderController.class)
@WebMvcTest
class OrdersIntegrationTest
```

to this:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {OrderController.class, OrdersExceptionHandler.class})
@WebMvcTest
class OrdersIntegrationTest
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Boot 2.x, but it seems MockMvcBuilders is not required anymore or as we are defining the ControllerAdvice as part of the Configuration, it gets loaded.

```
@WebMvcTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
  UserEndpoint.class, //the controller class for test
  WebConfiguration.class, //security configurations, if any
  StandardRestExceptionInterpreter.class. //<-- this is the ControllerAdvice class
})
@WithMockUser(username = "test@asdf.com", authorities = {"DEFAULT"})
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class UserEndpointTests {

@Test
@Order(3)
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenRegisteringDuplicateUser() throws Exception {
    //do setup...
    Mockito.doThrow(EntityExistsException.class).when(this.userService).register(user);

    this.mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                    .post("/users")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(this.objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user)))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isConflict());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just had the same issue, but solved it by adding the advicer to the classes in the @SpringBootTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyController.class, MyControllerAdvice.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestConfig.class})
@EnableWebMvc
```