# Status expected:<200> but was:<404> in spring test

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I have this class:

```
    package controllers;

    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

    import java.util.HashSet;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;


    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

    import com.epam.hhsystem.model.candidate.Candidate;
    import com.epam.hhsystem.services.CandidateService;
    import com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.CandidateMenuController;
    import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.*;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;


    import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.*;

    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
    import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;


    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/test/BeanConfig.xml" })
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @WebAppConfiguration
    public class CandidateControllerTest {

        @Mock(name = "candidateService")
        private CandidateService candidateService;

        @InjectMocks
        private CandidateMenuController candidateMenuController = new CandidateMenuController();

        @Autowired
        WebApplicationContext wac;

        MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void before() {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
              this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();

        }
@Test 
    public void testgoToCandidateMenuMockMvc() throws Exception { 
        //MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/goToCandidateMenu");


        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/goToCandidateMenu");
        ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(request);
        result.andExpect(status().isOk());
     }
}
```

When I execute it I see:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:89)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers$5.match(StatusResultMatchers.java:549)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:141)
at controllers.CandidateControllerTest.testgoToCandidateMenuMockMvc(CandidateControllerTest.java:104)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Controller code:

```
@Controller
public class CandidateMenuController extends AbstractController {
...
@RequestMapping("/goToCandidateMenu")
    public String goToCandidateMenu() {
        return "candidateMenu";
    }
...
}
```

Can you help me to fix my problem?

**UPDATE**

BeanConfig.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <!-- Включаем опцию использования конфигурационных аннотаций (@Annotation-based configuration)-->
        <context:annotation-config />


        <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.jpa" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="com.epam.hhsystem.services" />

        <!-- Файл с настройками ресурсов для работы с данными (Data Access Resources) -->
        <import resource="data.xml" />

    </beans>
```

data.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<!-- Настраивает управление транзакциями с помощью аннотации @Transactional -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- Менеджер транзакций -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Непосредственно бин dataSource -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        p:url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.16.9.52:1433;databaseName=hhsystemTest;"
        p:username="userNew" 
        p:password="Pass12345" />

    <!-- Настройки фабрики сессий Хибернейта -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:test/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
<!--                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop> -->
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: We'll need to see your context. Also, where do you initialize `mockMvc`?

Comment: Look at log output. If you're getting a 404, the server will usually tell you why.

Comment: why would someone downvote an IMHO legitimate question like this?

Comment: @StefanHaberl I downvoted because the question _does not show any research effort_. It a simple dump of a problem.

Comment: I made a mistake when I posted my topic. please read.

Comment: Post your configuration.

Comment: I must to post web.xml?

Comment: i am added configuration to topic

Comment: M. Deinum, Do you have not ideas?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Still, I don't get it. What about questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-get-which-radio-is-selected-via-jquery?rq=1 They don't show ANY kind of research and get an upvote of +600! Stackoverflow feels more and more hostile to me because of these downvotes!

Comment: @StefanHaberl That question applies to a very wide audience. This question applies only to OP. That doesn't mean we won't answer it.

Comment: If I were you I'd remove the name of the company you work for in the import section ;-)

Comment: @Enrico Giurin it was not commercial project. It was some sort of educational project.

Comment: @StefanHaberl Because Stackoverflow is not a forum where people help you code, it is a knowledge base where people can post common issues so that their resolution may be reused. The question you linked is basically 'I don't know a very basic feature', thus this Q&A becomes a google-indexed documentation page. This question is 'I screwed up my integration test, please review my entire project and tell me where I'm wrong' => absolutely 0 reusability.

Comment: @StefanHaberl When we say 'research effort' it does not mean that we judged the user 'not worthy' of an error, it means that the user did not follow the guideline to post a 'minimal reusable question'. It's even worse because the user got several tests red and posted several question for every failing test. If someone has trouble with setting up a MockMvcServer, they should post a minimal question explaining what they've done to set it up and explain the result rather than asking to people to fix specific tests.

Comment: 7 years later and I still disagree. K, this is no great question, BUT the OP gets downvoted for a real problem he has (I don’t judge his problem solving capabilities here). And the very basic jQuery question I linked has now 2500+ upvotes. SO still rewards the silliest, most rudimentary questions most. Which I still believe is wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Your test setup is wrong you aren't initializing the `MockMvc` correctly and that is al clearly in the reference guide. FIrst of all you have twice the initializing code and you aren't assing the result of the call to the `build` method. So you are basically left with an empty `MockMvc` object.

```
@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();
    MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();
}
```

Should be

```
@Before
public void before() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).dispatchOptions(true).build();
}
```

As stated this is all explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework).

Comment: Sorry, I posted wrong code.(posted comments). My code is like your variant. But I have old problem. I fixed mustake in my post

Comment: Besides this, in my case I was missing a forward slash "/" at the beginning of the url

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was missing the below annotation and was getting this error.

```
@WebMvcTest(UserStatsController.class)
public class UserStatsControllerTest {
  ..
}
```

Note that the class of the controller and **NOT the test**.
Make sure as well if you load other class using @ContextConfiguration(**NOT the test**) not load test class.

Comment: Thanks mate, simple but helpful answer! I was using UserStatsController**Test**.class, hahaha :(

Answer (score 4):

I believe you just haven't enabled `<mvc:annotation-driven>` in your `beanconfig.xml` and so your `@Controller` classes just aren't being registered.

Add this

```
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my working solution. Hope it helps.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SimpleTest  {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .build();
    }

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {        
    mockMvc.perform(get("/simple")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().is(200));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added this annotations to configuration class and work it:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ResourceTest {

   ...

   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @ComponentScan( basePackages = { "..." } )
   static class ContextConfiguration {
   }
}
```

Comment: There are 6 annotations appear here, which one did you add?

Comment: All you see on ContextConfiguration and @ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader.class)

Answer (score 1):

In the case that you make a really stupid "going to fast for your own good" typo like I did, make sure that your controller test class does NOT have the same name as the controller class itself. Most people know this, but you can get into this same error condition the names are identical, and it may not my immediately obvious why. To clarify further, make sure you DO NOT DO THIS:

Controller name: `MyController`
Test class name: `MyController`

This can cause your MockMvc tests to fail with status 404... which is not very obvious.
Naming [obviously] should be more like:

Controller name: `MyController`
Test class name: `MyControllerTest`

Answer (score 1):

My problem was I did not have @ComponentScan() it was pretty embarrassing.
It was also hard to find.I,myself overlooked my SpringBootApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Following is what i did in spring mvc which worked fine (explained as unable to find direct reference)
Controller class as folowing

```
            package rndpurpose.controller;

            @RestController
            @RequestMapping("/springmvc")
            public class urlController {

                @CrossOrigin
                @RequestMapping(value = "managepostReq", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
                public Map<String, Object> managepostReq()
                {
                    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();

                    //System.out.println(data);
                    response.put("status", true);

                    return response;
                }
            }
```

Inside rndpurpose.text (package) > created package related to same as my @ComponentScan in WebConfig.java created test class

```
            package rndpurpose.test;

            import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;
            import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
            import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
            import org.json.JSONObject;
            import org.junit.Test;
            import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
            import junit.framework.Assert;

            public class UrlcontrollerTest extends JunitAbstract {

                @Test
                @Order(1)
                public void firsttestcase() throws Exception {
                /*jai ganesha*/
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonGetData = new JSONObject();
                        jsonGetData.put("username", "name");
                        
                        ResultActions resultActions = postRequest("/springmvc/managepostReq", jsonGetData.toString());
                        MvcResult mvcResult = resultActions.andExpect(status().isOk())
                                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                                .andReturn();

                        
                        JSONObject reqResponse = new JSONObject(mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString());
                        System.out.println(reqResponse);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("ERROR"+ e);
                    }
                }

            }
```

And JunitAbstract for handling req

```
            package rndpurpose.test;
            import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
            import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart;
            import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
            import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
            import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
            import java.nio.charset.Charset;
            import org.junit.Before;
            import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
            import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
            import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
            import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
            import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
            import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
            import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultActions;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder;
            import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
            import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
            import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
            import rndpurpose.config.WebConfig;
            @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
            @ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class)
            @WebAppConfiguration
            @ComponentScan(basePackages="rndpurpose")
            public abstract class JunitAbstract {

                public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

                private MockMvc mockMvc;

                @Autowired
                public WebApplicationContext wac;


                @Before
                public void setup() {
                    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
                    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
                }

                public ResultActions postRequest(String url, String bodyData) {
                    ResultActions resultActions = null;
                    try {
                        System.out.println(url);
                        resultActions = mockMvc.perform(post(url).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(bodyData));
                                
                    }
                    
                    catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Error while executing post req "+ e);
                    }
                    return resultActions;
                }

                public ResultActions getRequest(String url) {
                    ResultActions resultActions = null;
                    try {
                        resultActions = this.mockMvc.perform(get(url)).andDo(print());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Error while executing test case for get"+ e);
                    }
                    return resultActions;
                }

                public ResultActions multipartFileUpload(String url, MultiValueMap<String, String> bodyMap,
                        MockMultipartFile... files) {
                    ResultActions resultActions = null;
                    try {
                        MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder builder = multipart(url);
                        addMultipartFiles(builder, files);
                        if (bodyMap != null)
                            builder.params(bodyMap);
                        resultActions = mockMvc.perform(builder);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Error in multipartFileUpload "+ e);
                    }
                    return resultActions;
                }

                private void addMultipartFiles(MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder builder, MockMultipartFile... files) {
                    if (files != null) {
                        for (MockMultipartFile file : files) {
                            builder.file(file);
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

and pom looks like this

```
    <!-- test starts -->


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.19</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test ends -->
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was missing @ComponentScan("my.package.*") on MyApplication class because my controller was in a different package than MyApplication class.


Do check the debugger tick mark in debugging mode. if the component is getting scanned it will show as Tick mark else it will not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar error when my controllers were not loaded , in case of spring  mvc with .xml based dispatcher servlet i was able to fix it by adding @ContextConfiguration
as following

Has a bean to connect db

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig  {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(WebConfig.class);

@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    final CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);
    resolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);
    return resolver;
}
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    
     dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.2.29:5432/trintiygisenterprise");
     dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
     dataSource.setUsername("postgres"); 
     dataSource.setPassword("track@123");
     
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public Connection getConnectionObject() {
    Connection con  = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/t26",
                 "postgres", "track@123");

         System.out.println("====================CONNECTED TO DB================ "+con);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return con;

}

@Bean
@Autowired
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {

    return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
}
```

and it will be scanned in springrest-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com" />
 <mvc:annotation-driven />  
<!--  <mvc:resources mapping="/*" location="/" />-->

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
<bean class="com.config.WebConfig"/>
</beans>
```

and the web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Controller lookes like this

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class bootsrapController {


/**
@GetMapping("/second")
**/
@RequestMapping(value = "second", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = 
"Accept=application/json")
public Map<String, Object> second() 
{
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put("second", true);
    result.put("status", true);
return result;
}
}
```

Testcontroller as follows

```
public class UrlcontrollerTest extends JunitAbstract {
    @Test
@Order(1)
public void unittestcreatelayergroup(){

    try {

        System.out.println("Running test");
        
        final ResultActions resultActions = getRequest("/api/second");
        System.out.println(resultActions);
        
        final MvcResult mvcResult = resultActions
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("status", is(true)))
                .andReturn(); 
}
    catch (final Exception e) {

        LOGGER.error(e.getStackTrace());

    }
}
```

and unit test for get req as follows

```
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/springrest-servlet.xml") 
@WebAppConfiguration
public abstract class JunitAbstract {

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(JunitAbstract.class);

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
public WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

public ResultActions getRequest(String url) {
    LOGGER.info("sending req--------: "+url);

    ResultActions resultActions = null;
    try {
        resultActions = this.mockMvc.perform(get(url)).andDo(print());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while executing test case for get"+ e);
    }
    return resultActions;
}
```

thanks to @tunguski answer too [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302243/spring-mvc-controllers-unit-test-not-calling-controlleradvice/18911362#18911362)

[image]