# Spring Boot, Global Exception Handling and Testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, error-handling

Long story short. My service, throws EntityNotFound exceptions. By default Spring boot doesn't know what kind exception is that and how to treat it and simply displays a "500 Internal Server Error".

I had no choice but implementing my own exception handling mechanism.

There are several ways to resolve this issue with Spring boot. And I chose to use the @ControllerAdvice with @ExceptionHandler methods.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleNotFound(EntityNotFoundException exception, HttpServletRequest webRequest) {
    ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(
            new Date(),
            HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
            exception,
            webRequest.getServletPath());

    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
 }
}
```

So when the exception is being thrown, the new handler catches the exception and returns a nice json containing a message, like:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-06-10T08:10:32.388+0000",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"exception": "EntityNotFoundException",
"message": "Unknown employee name: test_name",
"path": "/assignments"
}
```

Implementing - not that hard. Hardest part is testing.

First of all, while testing spring doesn't seem to know of the new handler in test mode.
How can i tell spring to be aware of a new implementation for handling such errors?

```
@Test
public void shouldShow404() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(post("/assignments")
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .content(new ClassPathResource("rest/assign-desk.json").getInputStream().readAllBytes()))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
```

As I see it, this test should pass but it doesn't.

Any thoughts are welcome. Thank You!

Comment: How are you initializing the test class? What runner are you using?

Comment: "@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) @SpringBootTest @AutoConfigureMockMvc'code"

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer.

For whom it may concern:

Settings apon class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerTest{
//
}
```

and the test:

```
@Test
public void catchesExceptionWhenEntityNotFoundWithSpecificResponse() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/assignments")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(new ClassPathResource("rest/assign-desk.json").getInputStream().readAllBytes()))
            .andExpect(status().isNotFound())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("status").value(404))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("exception").value("EntityNotFoundException"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("message").value("Unknown employee name: abc"));
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302243/spring-mvc-controllers-unit-test-not-calling-controlleradvice) or [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12979). Don't know how you setup your test class. But if you have your test class anotated with [WebMvcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html), all controllers and controller advices should be registered.

Comment: "@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc"

Comment: Did you try WebMvcTest?