# Expecting exception during MockMVC.perform in JUnit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit5

This may be a repeated question. But I have gone through some 10-15 related posts and associated responses which have not resolved my issue. The issue that I am facing is as here below
I have a SpringRest controller class with custom ApplicationException.
I have written a Junit for my controller and here below is the snippet where I am facing issue.

```
this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(url)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(new ObjctMapper().writeValueAsString(requestObject)
        .headers(header)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    )
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status().is4xxClientError());
```

When I execute the test method, I see that ApplicationException is thrown from the code, but the Junit fails and what I see in Junit Console is

```
"org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is com.abc.pmr.case.exception.ApplicationException at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
...
...
Caused by: com.abc.pmr.case.exception.ApplicationException
    at com.abc.pmr.case.exception.ApplicationException
```

I tried with  `.andExpect(mvcresult -> assertTrue(mvcresult.getResolvedException() instanceof ApplicationException));` as well.
But that did not help either.

The Junit fails with the above said exception, while I want to pass the Junit with the expected Exception as ApplicationException.
Note: All the success scenario testcases in this class are passing successfully.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any handler logic for your exception? You've tried `getResolvedException`, but it will only `Return any exception raised by a handler and successfully resolved through a HandlerExceptionResolver.` from [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MvcResult.html#getResolvedException--)

Comment: Yes, I do have an exception handler which further calls a transformer class that builds the complete error response along with error code, error messages, etc.

Comment: Could you add your exception handler listing here?

Comment: Are you sure, the exception thrown by your controller is in 400 range? Can please add the response of Api for which it throws exception?

Comment: @evg_nyWill share the handler code shortly.

Comment: @wak786, If the exception is not in 400 range, it should give assertion error. But the control does not even come to the line next to mockmvc.perform

Comment: @evg_ny here is the method of the exception handler
```@ExceptionHandler(ApplicationException.class)
 public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAccountDetailsException(ApplicationException ex) {
  return errorResponseTransformer.populateDefaultErrorResponse(ex);
 }```

The transformer code is as here below
```return buildErrorResponse(ErrorEnum.BAD_REQUEST_ERROR, "" );```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your `mockMvc` setup is not completely correct for your case.
Make sure that you have set exception handler to your mockMvc.
You can find more info about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302243/spring-mvc-controllers-unit-test-not-calling-controlleradvice).

So, when your environment will be configured correct you will have an ability test this logic.

Comment: Great, let me know then how its going.

Comment: Awesome! You were on the spot!
Only issue is I see different ways to set exception handler in MockMVC.
Earlier I had written one which did not work.
The working one is here below
```this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(autowiredController).setControllerAdvice(autowiredExceptionHandler).build();```
Also on top of the class, I had to include the following
```@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyController.class, Services.class, ApplicationException.class, ExceptionHandler.class, ErrorTransformer.class})```
Thanks again!

Comment: This link gave me the exact snippet.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302243/spring-mvc-controllers-unit-test-not-calling-controlleradvice/28727831#28727831

Comment: Cool, so, it was pretty hard to give your concrete complete solution here because I don't know your full environment and spring setup.
But anyway if it helped you - please mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: I agree. I should have given you the @BeforeEach method contents, as that would have given you better idea. But could not share much of details as much of it are proprietary. So in the process of cutting down those pieces, I could have missed the required ones as well. Whatever... All good now.
Accepted! Thanks!

Comment: Great! Nice to hear it :)