# webMvc test not invoking the error handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am trying to write the integration test for my controller.

Exception handler is there in a library as part of dependency. But my webMvc Test is not able to invoke the handler

The exception is thrown from method

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class, excludeAutoConfiguration = {
    SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class WebMockTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private MyService service;

  
  @Test
  public void shall_make_get_call_404_not_ok() throws Exception {
    when(service.getById(any())).thenThrow(new CustomException("Not found"));
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/items/" + "12")).andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound());

  }
}
```

Here I am not able to get the response but exception is thrown from test method.

How do I trigger the exception handler.

Comment: You need add @Import(Exceptionhandler.class)

Comment: @AlexeyBril thank you. is there any option to include some base package.

Comment: As far as I could figure out, only if you do not specify a specific controller

Answer (score 0):

You need to add @Import(Exceptionhandler.class).

I described a similar problem, when using @WebMvcTest with specific controllers and its solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74191408/7789681